# I Did Something Really Dumb With My Oven, Suggestions? - KitchenAid kebs107sss00 Woes

Tags: wiring, oven

I am renovating my kitchen and installed a perfectly working used KitchenAid kebs107sss00 oven along with a new cooktop.
Tonight when the wife went to use the induction cooktop she was getting an error due to low voltage.

The cooktop has a green, black, and white wire and is 240v.
I immediately realized I connected the white to the neutral and thus was only getting 110v to the cooktop.
I switched off the breaker and connected the wires correctly, or so I thought, as I was not focusing and chatting to my wife and ended up connecting the neutral wire from the oven to to red 110V wire from the oven and wall thinking that wire was the cooktop wire!!

I went and flipped the breaker and heard a weird clicking noise from the oven followed by an ozone like smell and I turned the breaker off ASAP (*the clicking must have been the transformer flipping the locking self cleaning mechanism*).
The oven door is now locked and nothing is working :(
I reconnected the wires correctly but I fear the worst.

Any suggestions?

The thermal breaker inside the oven is OK, I am getting continuity so I am not sure if I fried the front panel or what I could have done on such a STUPID rookie move I would normally not make.
I can see no damage to any caps or resistors or anything on the main board or front panel board FYI, nothing is burnt or black.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: just to clarify, you fed a 110v oven 240v? I would probe your DC voltages on the boards. Hopefully they are 0v anywhere to anywhere and you can replace the power supply or a 1-time fuse. If they do have DC as expected but do nothing, that's bad...

Comment: Actually, it sounds like he fed 240 volts to the 120 volt portion of a 120/240 volt oven. But same difference.

Comment: Don't beat yourself up; it happens.  Save all that money being a DIYer, then give some of it back with moves like this.

Comment: The thermal breaker is for overheating, not for neutral to hot short. If you have a multi meter, check for voltages on the transformer. No more chatting when doing electrical work.

Comment: Well I fed 110v to the neutral line, not 240v. 
I only connected the white neutral line to the red, not both red and black. 
Man, guys...this RUINED my night I tell ya...I had a HORRIBLE sleep, dreamt about it and would wake up bummed. 
To top it off it is my 50th birthday today and talk about a shitty start to it LOL. 

I agree about the thermal breaker, that should have no effect on what I did. 
There appear to be 3 transformers, one for the faceplate, one for the blower motor, and another in-between those two, seen in the attached photo:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/2jSP5QoszeuioKtU7

Comment: Also appears to be a ceramic ballast resistor which has no short when testing with ohms.

Comment: That Transformer is rated for 110 volts so if I fed110v to it through the neutral line that shouldn't fry the Transformer, should it?

Comment: I think I found the culprit lol. photos.app.goo.gl/bk4tXnVGeXnQizNZ6 Hopefully this was the sacrificial lamb so to speak and no damage to the boards was done as a result.

Answer (score 1):

To unlock the oven door, fashion a hook out of coat hanger wire. While putting moderate opening pressure on the door handle, disengage the latch by pulling it to the side with the hook.

Comment: That worked, thanks Phil. 
Now I need to figure out what I fried lol. 
Cheers